# Maximum path sum triangle, how to find the elements which were added

Tags: c++

The Euler triangle problem is to find the max sum from the first number to one of the last numbers (the last row)

So the input can be:

```
5 //the number of rows
7
3 8
8 1 0
2 7 4 4
4 5 2 6 5
```

Output should be:

```
30
7 3 8 7 5
```

I am able to find the SUM (ex. 30) but I cannot find a way to properly find all the elements that were summed up.

Here is the function:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int m;
        cin >> m;

       int tri[m][m];

    for(int i=0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cin >> tri[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=m-2; i>=0; i--)
     {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (tri[i+1][j] > tri[i+1][j+1])
            {
                tri[i][j] += tri[i+1][j];
            }
            else
                tri[i][j] += tri[i+1][j+1];
        }
     }



  cout << tri[0][0];
     return 0;
    }
```

---

The approach with matrix of vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m;
    cin >> m;

    vector<int> tri[m][m];

    int input;
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cin >> input;
            tri[i][j].push_back(input);
        }
    }

    //make other entries zero        
    for(int i=0; i < m; i++)
         for(int j=0; j < m; j++)
             for(unsigned int k=0; k < tri[i][j].size(); k++)
                 if(tri[i][j][k] > 1000)               
                      tri[i][j][k] = 0;

    vector<int> input_vec;
    int sum_of_elem1, sum_of_elem2;
    for (int i=m-2; i>=0; i--)
     {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            sum_of_elem1 = accumulate(tri[i+1][j].begin(), tri[i+1][j].end(), 0);
            sum_of_elem2 = accumulate(tri[i+1][j+1].begin(), tri[i+1][j+1].end(), 0);

            if (sum_of_elem1 > sum_of_elem2)
            {
                tri[i][j] = tri[i+1][j];
            }else
                tri[i][j] = tri[i+1][j+1];
        }
     }


      int sum_of_elem3 = accumulate(tri[0][0].begin(), tri[0][0].end(), 0);

      cout << sum_of_elem3;

      for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
      {
        cout << tri[0][0][i] << " ";
      }

      for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
         {
           for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
             {
               tri[i][j].clear();
             }
         }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's very simple. Instead of merely storing a single value, a sum, in each element as you go up to the root, store the actual values themselves, that make up the sum. Problem solved.

Comment: In `for(int i=0; i < (m*(m+1))/2; ++i)` if I try your example input `7` makes the loop run for 28 times but you enter 14 items am I missing something?

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman it goes 28 times because 7 rows means 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 elemens in one triangle which add up to 28

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I still can't get it can you help me with it?

Comment: A better (and easier) way to do this is to go backwards. That is, start from last row, and add to upper rows and eventually you get maximum sum. You can also incorporate @SamVarshavchik's suggestion and also store the paths as well.

Comment: @Annabelle Yes I tried to implement the the bottom-up approach it works but I am still confused how to get the numbers then were chosen to sum up

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well I don't think its that easy because if I keep all the sums as you said to store them instead of summing in the beginning I am left with a very weird array, can you please describe what can I do in details

Comment: What part of "store the actual values instead of their sum" you did not understand? Instead of `int tri[m][m];` replace that with `std::vector<int> tri[m][m];`. Now, simply reproduce your existing logic, but instead of a single value in each position, you have a list of values to consider, as a single sum. It shouldn't take more than hour for you to change your existing code. Nothing else needs to change.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are u suggesting to put everything in a single vector instead of a matrix? To be honest now its more complicated for me to understand, it would really help me if you could comment in the post and at least do something which I can then follow?!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I meant answer instead of "commet"

Comment: No, I did not suggest using a single vector. I was clear: a matrix of vectors, instead of a matrix of `int`s. Instead of each element in the matrix being a single `int` value, it's a vector of values, that sum up to the actual value for that matrix element. If you do not understand that, writing any code would be pointless since you won't understand it. And if you do understand the solution, but having some problems implementing it in C++, then the right person to turn to would be your teacher or instructor in your C++ class, for this assignment. They're paid to teach you, and help you.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I should have a matrix which stores vectors, and then when an element is changed I have to put that value in the corresponding vector, and then I will end up with a matrix of vectors with different sizes of course, and then how can I extract the numbers which were add up, this is the part which I do not get ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Look up, I have started with your recommendation , just tell me if I am on the right track!

Comment: Yes. You now initialized the matrix correctly. Now, all you have to do is reimplement your algorithm. Except that instead of comparing two elements, `[i+1][j]` and `[i+1][j+1]` to see which one is highest, you sum up all the values in each vector, from each element. And whichever vector's sum is the highest, take that element's vector, and copy all the values from that element's vector into `[i][j]`. That's not so complicated, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170440/discussion-between-dan-and-sam-varshavchik).